# Where does Chrome download synced extensions from?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

Say I was to sign into a new user on Chrome and had extensions from a previous computer synced to my account. Where are these extensions downloaded from after I sign? I thought maybe `update_url` in manifest.json but I'm not sure.

Comment: Almost certainly the usual Chrome Web Store source.

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine an actual sync payload through `chrome://sync-internals/`

```json
"SPECIFICS": {
  "encrypted": true,
  "extension": {
    "disable_reasons": "0",
    "enabled": true,
    "id": "ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle",
    "incognito_enabled": false,
    "installed_by_custodian": false,
    "name": "Desktop Notifications for Stack Exchange",
    "remote_install": false,
    "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "version": "1.6.12"
  }
},
```

From this, Chrome does see the `update_url`, which it can query for the download URL according to [auto-update protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/autoupdate). Note that the actual extension is *not* hosted at that URL, that URL merely contains instructions on where to download it from. In this instance, the download will be from the Chrome Web Store.

It will also sync disabled status across instances: a disabled extension will still be downloaded, but will be disabled immediately.

Since non-enterprise versions can't install from anywhere but CWS, and non-CWS enterprise installs take their `update_url`s from policies and not Sync, I think the answer to your question is almost certainly "from CWS". Can't test it though.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but from an enterprise standpoint where would Chrome download the synced extension from if it wasn't on CWS? (Say a Custom app that is force-installed from the Google Apps Administration Panel)

Comment: Literally anywhere. You can specify path to CRX which can the contain an arbitrary `update_url`. But you're confusing Google Apps Suite (private CWS items)and [enterprise install](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453) mechanisms.